# Knowing about illegal immigrants

Tags: customs-and-immigration

If I know someone who has emigrated to the USA illegally and is working there as well what can I do and what happens if I report them to ICE.

And if ICE does act upon the person will my personal information be revealed to the person who is violating US laws?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to traveling.

Comment: Possibly on-topic at [expatriates.se].

Answer (score 2):

> [How can I report illegal activity](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/735/~/reporting-illegal-activity)?
>
> General Illegal Activity Call 1-800-BE-ALERT
>
> Illegal Aliens
>
> If you would like to report illegal aliens, please call Immigration and Customs Enforcement (ICE) at 1-866-DHS-2ICE (347-2423). They will need to know names, locations (either work place or residence) and any other specific information you can provide.  Visit www.ice.gov for more information.
>
> Should you wish to submit an anonymous tip via phone, you may call the HSI Tip Line at (866) 347-2423.
>
> [HSI Tip Form](https://www.ice.gov/webform/hsi-tip-form#wcm-survey-target-id)
>
> Disclosure: In order to submit a tip using this web form, the disclosure of your contact information in this web form is voluntary. Should you wish to submit an anonymous tip via phone, you may call the HSI Tip Line at (866) 347-2423.
>   TTY for hearing impaired only: (802) 872-6196